# What are the pandoc command line options to color and underline hyperlinks in PDF output?

Tags: pdf, latex, pandoc

Basically the title question -- I want the links in my pdf document to be blue and underlined (instead of hidden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full solution involves setting the underline in the markdown file

```
[[Link text]{.underline}](http://www.google.com)
```

as per the 8.12.6 in [the documentation](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/8.12-inline-formatting.html).  Note I had to install [ulem.sty from CTAN](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.sty).  The `span` based approach might work too, didn't test it.

Then include the `--variable colorlinks=true` in the pandoc command:

```
pandoc -o output.pdf --variable colorlinks=true input.md
```

Answer (score 3):

A half solution, which colors the links is:

`pandoc -o output.pdf --variable colorlinks=true input.md`